# FAT32 SD Cards and Other Removeable Drives Give Off Read Only Error and Input/Output Errors

Tags: readonly, fat32

Distro: Debian 12.0 (Bookworm)
Greetings,  I really need help with with an error I get on seemingly every sd card or portable storage device formatted to fat32 that I use. Basically, whenever I try to make changes to an sd card (things like deleting files, unzipping, etc.) I always get the following errors. for example when i try to make a change like removing a file (with sudo):

```
rm: cannot remove 'nimdsphax_v1.0.zip': Read-only file system
```

I have also tried different adaptors and commands like:

```
mount | grep /dev/sdb1
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 -o remount,rw
```

and

```
sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb
```

but nothing is fixed

Any help on this would be a great help.

Comment: SD cards have a little hardware switch that sets write-protection (usually left side). Did you check that? Did you confirm that the SD card device is `/dev/sdb`?